# Get the row with first occurrence of repetitive value in column using SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, repeat, find-occurrences

Suppose I have this table

```
Id   Order Value
------------------
aa   0     'cat'
ba   1     'dog'
bb   2     'yuk'
dc   3     'gen'
ca   4     'cow'
c1   5     'owl'
b0   7     'ant'
h9   8     'fly'
t4   9     'bee'
g2   10    'fox'
ea   11    'rat'
fa   12    'pig'
gu   13    'pig'
co   14    'pig'
fo   15    'pig'
ou   16    'pig'
eo   17    'pig'
ii   18    'pig'
```

What is the query in order to obtain:

```
fa   12    'pig'
```

Like you can see, the next rows after 12 till 18. All these rows have a `pig` in the `Value` column.

How determine the row where the repetition began?

Thanks

Comment: As in: the first row for which the next row has the same `Value` when ordered by `Order`? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Or perhaps you mean the first row for *every* repetition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `WITH TIES` option in concert with the window functions `lead()` and `row_number()`

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([Id] varchar(50),[Order] int,[Value] varchar(50))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('aa',0,'cat')
,('ba',1,'dog')
,('bb',2,'yuk')
,('dc',3,'gen')
,('ca',4,'cow')
,('c1',5,'owl')
,('b0',7,'ant')
,('h9',8,'fly')
,('t4',9,'bee')
,('g2',10,'fox')
,('ea',11,'rat')
,('fa',12,'pig')
,('gu',13,'pig')
,('co',14,'pig')
,('fo',15,'pig')
,('ou',16,'pig')
,('eo',17,'pig')
,('ii',18,'pig')
 
Select top 1 with ties *
 From @YourTable
 Order By case when lead(value,1) over (order by [order]) = value then 1 else 2 end
         ,row_number() over (order by [Order])
```

**Results**

```
Id  Order   Value
fa  12      pig
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the *first row* where a repetition occurs, you can use `LEAD` to get the next value per row, `ORDER BY` to sort and `TOP (1)` to get the first result

```sql
SELECT TOP (1) *
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        LEAD([Value]) OVER (ORDER BY [Order]) nextValue
    FROM tbl
) t
WHERE nextValue = [Value]
ORDER BY [Order];
```

If you want the first row for *every* repetition, you can use `LEAD` to get the next value per row, and `LAG` to get the one before. Then you check whether the next value is the same, but the previous one is different

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        LEAD([Value]) OVER (ORDER BY [Order]) nextValue,
        LAG([Value]) OVER (ORDER BY [Order]) prevValue
    FROM tbl
) t
WHERE nextValue = [Value]
AND (prevValue <> [Value] OR prevValue IS NULL)
ORDER BY [Order];
```